# Spring add authentication manager to filter

Tags: java, spring-security

How to configure spring to use AuthenticationManager with my custom implementation of UserDetailService in http basic authentication?

I tried this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http, PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManager authManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
            .userDetailsService(new UserDetailServiceImpl(userManager))
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(new DaoAuthenticationProvider()).build();
    http.httpBasic().configure(http.authenticationManager(authManager));
    return http.build();
}
```

But the BasicAuthentication filter does not register the authManager.

I could do something like:

```
 BasicAuthenticationFilter filter = new BasicAuthenticationFilter(authManager);
 http.addFilter(filter);
```

But there might be a different, more standard way to do it.

Comment: Why are you both enabling httpBasic, and adding a custom basicauthentication filter. Why are you just not configuring the one spring provides for you.

Comment: That's what I wanted but I was struggling to configure it using my authManager.

Comment: Why do you need a custom authManager? Read the docs for FormLogin, all you need to do is to provide a PasswordEncoder and a UserDetailsService as `@Bean` and the framework will create everything for you under the hood.

Comment: Not sure if you read the question correctly I'm trying to set up Basic authentication not FormLogin

Comment: the same rules apply https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/basic.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/user-details-service.html#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice

Answer (score 0):

Okay apparently no need to configure authentication manager. For basic authentication it's enough to provide UserDetailService like so:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configureFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(bookieAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().userDetailsService(new UserDetailServiceImpl(userManager))
                .formLogin().disable()
                .and().build()
```